# Mirror network directory structure (not files) locally with C#

Tags: c#

### Background:

I'm using a 3rd party program for controlling a camera that saves the captured images to a network drive. However, the server has a relatively high latency and the camera software is saving the file in (presumably too) small packets so that each save operation is "blocking" the software for upwards of 10 minutes. If the image is saved locally the save operation is (near) instantaneous and copying the locally saved image to the network drive in Windows is also as fast as expected/immediate. It's only saving images directly to the server that's causing issues.

My idea to circumvent this problem is to save the image locally and use the `FileSystemWatcher` to detect new files and copy them over to the network drive. To do this I need to mirror the network drive's directory structure locally so that users can simply select a local directory to which the camera software will save the file. I thought to copy the existing directory structure (recursively using `GetDirectories()` and `CreateDirectory()`) and then starting a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor the network drive for any changes in the directory structure and replicate those changes locally.

### Problem:

The network drive currently has roughly 45k directories and the initial mirroring takes too long (just under 1 hour). Since this would have to be run each time the computer/program starts, this lead time is unacceptable.

Here's the code that I use for the initial directory structure mirroring:

```
public static void MirrorDirectoryTree(string sourceDir, string destinationDir, bool recursive)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            if (recursive)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dirs)
                {
                    string newDestinationDir = Path.Combine(destinationDir, subDir.Name);
                    MirrorDirectoryTree(subDir.FullName, newDestinationDir, true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }

        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDir);
    }
```

Is there a way to speed up this initial directory structure mirroring? Or would another approach altogether (e.g. somehow intercepting the Save As procedure of the camera software and changing the destination path or forcing Windows to "cache" the file locally before copying it to the network drive) be the better solution? The idea, of course, is for it to make as little change to the users' habits as possible.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Are you sure the delay isn't caused by a few thousand `UnauthorizedAccessException` errors? This kind of recursion is very inefficient too. You can retrieve all directories with a single call if you pass the correct parameters to `GetDirectories` or even better, `EnumerateDirectories`

Comment: Why do you need this local replication? Is it not enough to just save the file locally and than copy them to the final file system on the server?

Comment: You should just use a proper file replication service. Look at Windows DFS, or Resilio Sync. Don't reinvent the wheel, it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @MarcoBeninca I need a way of knowing where to copy the files (path on the server). If the local structure is the same as on the server, the user can simply select the local directory and the C# program running in the background will copy the image from the local directory to the same directory on the server. That was the idea at least... Manually copying files is of course possible, but rather tedious so nobody would be happy with that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the real problem is exceptions thrown by inaccessible folders. Listing 45K folders shouldn't take that long.

Recursion isn't needed either. The `GetDirectories` overload allow searching nested directories.

The following code should return all directories and skip inaccessible ones:

```
var options=new EnumerationOptions
{
    IgnoreInaccessible=true,
    RecurseSubdirectories=true,
    BufferSize=16384
};
var dirs=dir.GetDirectories("*",options);
```

`GetDirectories` will wait until it receives all results before it starts. A better idea would be to use `EnumerateDirectories` to return results as they become available, eg :

```
foreach(var folder in dir.EnumerateDirectories("*",options))
{
    var relative=Path.GetRelativePath(dir.FullName,folder.FullName);
    var newPath=path.Combine(localRoot,relative);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
}
```

Comment: Using `EnumerateDirectories()` and the above specified options definitely helped, but, unfortunately, not enough. The lead time decreased from about 3300 seconds to 2600 seconds.

Also, I think that `Path.RelativeTo()` should be `Path.GetRelativePath()` and `folder.Name` should be `folder.FullName`.

Comment: Oops, fixed it. How fast is the code if you *don't* create new directories? If the other machine is slow (eg a slow network drive) there may not be much you can do. If folder creation causes delays you could use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to speed it up

Comment: Hmm, with `CreateDirectory()` commented out the code needed 2350 seconds. Looks like a lot of inquiries/packets are overwhelming the server somehow (although, as mentioned in the question, copying the image from windows works normally) and I'll have to try something else.

Comment: What kind of server is this? Windows machine? SAMBA server on a proper Linux box? An underpowered NAS? It matters. The cheaper NAS boxes have weak CPUs and limited RAM. Reading and translating metadata is more expensive than sending and receiving bytes for a single file. The metadata may not be cached at all.

Comment: What are the server's CPU and Disk IO doing when you're enumerating folders?

Comment: That info is out of my (direct) reach as the servers are maintained by the IT department. I'll have to go through them to find out and that might take some time... I'll post back when I have an update. Thanks for all the help so far!